# Are there any benefits of opting out of free PS plus games?

Tags: playstation-plus

I always was wondering if my free games of the month deal is somehow limited. I heard that there is a assurance that the games I get for free in PS plus should exceed particular cost.
At the same time it's just not very clear to me why these games are not given by default, I always should go into PS store and choose the games I want to get. Will it limit my future deals? Can I have only limited number of giveaways?

**Edit**.
Sorry for confusion, I don't want to know why I can't chose any game from the store. My question is "*Why aren't the free games added to my library by default? Are there any benefits of not adding them?*"

Comment: I guess it's as simple as: you get games for free but you still have to do something for it. In this case go to the store and select the game you want. An economic reason might be that if you miss the game while it's free you have to buy it afterwards.

Comment: @Wondercricket it makes sense, but I somewhat disagree - all free PS + games go under a separate category, so you can easily distinguish them as needed

Comment: I'm very confused by this... It's free games; you add them, you get them. You don't add them you don't and you miss out on a sweet deal alongside your network access.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there's no benefit for you to not select and download the games offered to you each month. PS Plus gets you a set number of games each month, decided by Sony--not adding these games to your library when available will offer you nothing except a missed game.

As to *why* the PS Network doesn't just automatically add those games to your library... they've never said why they don't, and I doubt they ever will, but there's a few obvious business benefits to *Sony* that they gain by not doing this:

**Gauge Customer Interest**: If 100% of your users get 100% percent of the games each month, you're limited in your ability to see what's popular. If 92% of your users add the RPG you're offering to their library, but only 80% of the users add the racing game you're offering, you now have valuable information about which genres are currently popular with your customer base, and you can potentially leverage that knowledge into more PS+ sales.

**Better Traffic to Market**: It's a well-known marketing tactic that just getting customers to walk inside your store increases sales, even if they don't intend to buy anything when they walk in. Forcing users to open the PSN store, where they'll be bombarded with ads for new and on-sale games, in order to get their free stuff, follows this marketing principle. (You can see people discussing this tactic working on them in the [/r/PlaystationPlus thread here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PlayStationPlus/comments/9l6d08/auto_adding_ps_plus_games_to_your_library/).)

**Future Sales**: If the game gets added to the library each month, and you forget to download a game you're interested in one month... well, no worries, you've got a copy in your library! The way it works currently, however, if you miss picking up your games then the PS Network--and the publishers of the games on offer--gets another chance at a future sale for every customer who forgets to download.

**People May Not Want Them**: It's worth noting that, sometimes, giving customers free things will upset them. See [the U2 free iTunes album PR disaster](https://www.cnn.com/2014/10/15/tech/web/u2-bono-free-itunes/index.html) for an example. People can have reasons to not want certain games in their library--imagine a religious person not wanting a game about evil gods, or a person with young children not wanting a violent game--and while of course the rational solution would then be 'don't sign up for a service that gives you free games', customers aren't always rational. Sony may benefit from heading similar PR disasters to Apple's off at the pass.

**TL;DR** the customer gains nothing from not claiming the free games. However, the businesses involved gain several benefits from keeping'not claiming the free games' an option.

Comment: "_and while of course the rational solution would then be 'don't sign up for a service that gives you free games'_"  You must have a different definition of rational than me.

Answer (score 0):

It's what the deal is. With PS Plus you pay PlayStation for the servers firstly. Added benefit is the free games you get. You can't just go and pick RDR2, God Of War and GTA5 as your free games for this month ans this makes no sense and they'd loose ALOT of money.

In reality Sony approaches different developers and negotiates with them if a game should appear in a PS+ promotion or not. The developer gets much less money for a single instance of their game but they do get alot more money due to the fact that most everyone has PS+ these days.

It's limited by Sony and the "unknown" factor that they decide which games to go into PS+ each month, and which deals have been successful with the game developers. They can't just giveaway that they do not own...

Comment: I'm asking a little bit different question. Sorry for confusion, please see my edits